# Unable to set up xtset function for panel data

Tags: panel, stata

I have panel data with different dates and object names.

I want to create panel var in Stata (function `pvar`), but I need to "tsset variables"

```
sort object date
by object: gen t = _n
encode object , gen(icode)
xtset icode t
```

I get this error message

```
t ambiguous abbreviation
```

Comment: `pvar` and `xtset` are commands not functions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem. Consider this

```
. webuse grunfeld

. xtset
       panel variable:  company (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  year, 1935 to 1954
                delta:  1 year

. gen t = time

. xtset company t
       panel variable:  company (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  t, 1 to 20
                delta:  1 unit
```

Here `t` would be an ambiguous abbreviation for `time`, but Stata's rules imply that it chooses `t`, so the ambiguity doesn't bite.

In your case, I would ask for the results of

```
describe t*
```